# re2: extracting multiple fields between paired delimiters

Tags: regex, re2

I have a log file. Each line (or record) in the log file retains the following format:

```
tsB{{2020-08-18 15:02:29,793}}tsE,fnB{{standard_task_runner.py}}fnE,lnB{{53}}lnE,lvlB{{INFO}}lvlE
```

**Here is what I want to do**:

1] Extract `2020-08-18 15:02:29,793` with timestamp as key

2] Extract `standard_task_runner.py` with module as key

3] Extract `53` with line as key

4] Extract `INFO` with loglvl as key

Using re2 tools, how can I do this?
The regular expression I have tried:

```
"(*tsB{{<timestamp>}}tsE) (*fnA{{<module>}}fnB) (*lnB{{<line>}}lnE) (*lvlB<loglvl>lvlE)"
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: @NathanBenton it's easily achieved by using the following regular expression `{{.+?}}` or `\{\{.+?\}\}`

Comment: Yes, sorry that was not noted: `"(*tsB{{<timestamp>}}tsE) (*fnA{{<module>}}fnB) (*lnB{{<line>}}lnE) (*lvlB<loglvl>lvlE)"`

Comment: What are the re2 tools? What you used does not look like a regex to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following regular expression will [match](https://regex101.com/r/xnIwQs/1)

- the timestamp
- the name of the script
- the line
- loglevel

```
{{.+?}}
```

### explanations

1. `{{` and `}}` match literal `{{` and `}}`
2. `.+?` will match any character untill it will find `}}` i.e it will stop on the first `}}`